# What's the best way to deliver a PDF to non-iOS mobile web browsers?

Tags: pdf, mobile-website

I've done a bit of research and found that while we know iOS handles PDFs very well, Android and others don't.

Has anyone found a best practice that can be applied across all mobile browsers to provide the best experience for all?

Thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me. It downloads and opens in the PDF reader program, (whatever that is...). (Nexus S, Android 2.3)

Answer (score 0):

We have been looking at converting the PDFs in HTML for your clients as HTML support seems much better than PDF on several mobile platforms. You can read up on the idea at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2011/05/pdf-to-html5-conversion/